# Error running app. No target device found

Tags: android

Tried to fix "Error running app. No target device found". here's what I tried Run>edit configuration. But I did not see the options to check the "Deployment Target Options" . Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Probably `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` is missing.

It should be where `<!--Hey!-->` is.

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--Hey!-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @sha If that worked, can you please accept the answer?